# How do we apply a function to an entire group in pandas and python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can we apply a function to an entire group in pandas dataframe in python? This is the code that I have so far:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['key1', 'key2'])
result_with_bla = df_grouped.magic_apply(myfunc)
```

Basically I want a magic_apply function that calls myfunc on every subgroup of the df_grouped rather than on every row. Does that exist?

Comment: Could you be more specific about how `magic_apply` will differ from `apply`?  Maybe give an example of `myfunc`?

Answer (score 1):

As @DSM points out the "magic apply" is simply called... [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply). It's a groupby method:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: g = df.groupby(['A'])

In [13]: def f(x):
             print(x)
             return len(x)

In [14]: g.apply(f)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  4

   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  4

   A  B
2  5  6 
Out[14]: 
A
1    2
5    1
dtype: int64
```

*Note: Confusingly, f is applied 3 times even though there are only two groups - this is because pandas needs to determine the return type.*